# Removing the "first" object from a Set

Tags: java, set, guava

Under certain situations, I need to evict the oldest element in a Java `Set`. The set is implemented using a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which makes this simple: just get rid of the first element returned by the set's iterator:

```
Set<Foo> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<Foo>();
// do stuff...
if (mySet.size() >= MAX_SET_SIZE)
{
    Iterator<Foo> iter = mySet.iterator();
    iter.next();
    iter.remove();
}
```

This is ugly: 3 lines to do something I *could* do with 1 line if I was using a `SortedSet` (for other reasons, a `SortedSet` is not an option here):

```
if (/*stuff*/)
{
    mySet.remove(mySet.first());
}
```

So is there a cleaner way of doing this, **without:**

- changing the `Set` implementation, or
- writing a static utility method?

Any solutions leveraging [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) are fine.

---

<sub>I am fully aware that sets do not have inherent ordering. I'm asking about removing the first entry as defined by iteration order.</sub>

Comment: Can you comment on why SortedSet isn't an option? It's possible that, with more information, someone may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: Why should the first element returned by the iterator be the oldest?

Comment: @RHSeeger, Sorted set is not an options because it Compares objects and sorts the by their natural order.  Objects don't track their insertion order into other Collection objects, so it is not possible to override or alter the natural ordering to mimic insertion order.

Comment: What about using a container object such that you have a SortedSet<OriginalClass,Date>, with an overridden comparison method that sorts based on the date added?

Comment: @RHSeeger: because I can add 1000 elements with the same timestamp (at the millisecond).

Comment: I can think of ways to get what you want, but the cleanest solutions (I can think of) all involve a custom Set/OrderedSet implementation. Do you have a good reason for not implementing your own version of Set/OrderedSet, even if the code involved is small?

Comment: `Do you have a good reason for not implementing your own version of Set/OrderedSet, even if the code involved is small?` Yes ... it's been done already ;)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

LinkedHashSet is a wrapper for LinkedHashMap which supports a simple "remove oldest" policy. To use it as a Set you can do

```
Set<String> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>(){
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, Boolean> eldest) {
        return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for a way that doesn't even require the explicit check and remove operation when adding objects

Comment: @Thomas, You also don't to worry about whether `addAll()` calls `add()` or not as this is take care of for you.

Comment: You learn something new everyday... this is a great technique! +1 well deserved!

Comment: Hm, I did not know about the `removeEldestEntry`. This seems like a nice way to do what I want. The _only_ hangup is that the `Set<Foo>` comes out of a Guava `SetMultimap`. I'm not actually `new`ing the set; it comes from `SetMultimap<String, Foo> cache = LinkedHashMultimap.create()` and later calling `cache.get("baz")` which returns the set I'm working with.

Comment: @Matt Ball: You could create a `Supplier<Set>` that uses this technique to make sets and use that with `Multimaps.newMultimap`.

Comment: @Colin and Peter: thanks, that combination worked perfectly. I accepted @Peter's answer since it got me 90% of the way there. Would you mind editing your comment into your answer so I can give you a `+1` for your `Supplier<Set>` suggestion? The irony of all this is that the _code_ to do this is far uglier (though the semantics are nicer).

Answer (score 36):

```java
    if (!mySet.isEmpty())
      mySet.remove(mySet.iterator().next());
```

seems to be less than 3 lines.

You have to synchronize around it of course if your set is shared by multiple threads.

Comment: +1 For being the shortest possible way to do it with JDK-only libraries.

Comment: Slower than using the `iterator.remove()` method.

Comment: @LaurentPireyn, Good point.  I'm leaving this answer as-is though and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you really need to do this at several places in your code, just write a static method.

The other solutions proposed are often slower since they imply calling the `Set.remove(Object)` method instead of the `Iterator.remove()` method.

```
@Nullable
public static <T> T removeFirst(Collection<? extends T> c) {
  Iterator<? extends T> it = c.iterator();
  if (!it.hasNext()) { return null; }
  T removed = it.next();
  it.remove();
  return removed;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With guava:

```
if (!set.isEmpty() && set.size() >= MAX_SET_SIZE) {
    set.remove(Iterables.get(set, 0));
}
```

I will also suggest an alternative approach. Yes, it it changing the implementation, but not drastically: extend `LinkedHashSet` and have that condition in the `add` method:

```
public LimitedLinkedHashSet<E> extends LinkedHashSet<E> {
    public void add(E element) {
         super.add(element);
         // your 5-line logic from above or my solution with guava
    }
}
```

It's still 5 line, but it is invisible to the code that's using it. And since this is actually a specific behaviour of the set, it is logical to have it within the set.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you're doing it is fine. Is this something you do often enough to be worth finding a shorter way? You could do basically the same thing with Guava like this:

```
Iterables.removeIf(Iterables.limit(mySet, 1), Predicates.alwaysTrue());
```

That adds the small overhead of wrapping the set and its iterator for limiting and then calling the `alwaysTrue()` predicate once... doesn't seem especially worth it to me though.

**Edit:** To put what I said in a comment in an answer, you could create a `SetMultimap` that automatically restricts the number of values it can have per key like this:

```
SetMultimap<K, V> multimap = Multimaps.newSetMultimap(map,
    new Supplier<Set<V>>() {
      public Set<V> get() {
        return Sets.newSetFromMap(new LinkedHashMap<V, Boolean>() {
          @Override protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry<K, V> eldestEntry) {
            return size() > MAX_SIZE;
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty one-line solution: `mySet.remove(mySet.toArray(new Foo[mySet.size()])[0])` ;)

However, I'd still go for the iterator solution, since this would be more readable and should also be faster.

Edit: I'd go for Mike Samuel's solution. :)

Comment: Ugh. Creating the array is such a waste. If you want a quick and dirty one-line solution, just put the OP's code in one line `mySet.iterator().next().remove()`

Comment: @wolfcastle That wouldn't compile since `mySet.iterator().next()` would return a `Foo` object. As stated, this is quite ugly and inperformant and I favor Mike's solution (which I didn't think of ;) ): `mySet.remove(mySet.iterator().next())`.